# Dockerized Spring Boot microservice freeze without reason

Tags: java, spring, docker, microservices, freeze

I have a microservices based project. Each microservice is a Spring Boot (v.2.0.0-RC2) app. I have also a discovery, config and gateway microservices based on Spring Cloud (Finchley). The whole system is deployed on test machine using Docker Compose.

I realized that one of the microservices freezes after receiving several subsequent requests from frontend app, in a short period of time. After this, it becomes unresponsive for further requests, and I receive read timeout from my gateway. The same occurs when calling this microservice directly, bypassing the gateway.

I have a spring boot admin instance, and I realized the microservice goes offline and online again every 5 minutes. Despite of that, nothing interesting occurs in logs. No memory issues observed.

Next remark: this problem occurs only when I start all system from docker compose in same time. When I restart this single microservice, I can't reproduce it anymore.

And the last:  the whole container of the microservice seems to be freezed. When I do 'docker stop' on it, the terminal hangs up, but after checking the container status in another terminal, the container appears as 'exited'. A very strange thing occured, when I did 'docker attach' on the container. The terminal also hung up and when I exited from it, my problematic microservice started to work properly and accepts incoming request with success.

Can anyone help me with this strange problem ? I have really no more ideas, what can I try to resolve it.

Thanks in advance for any clue.

**EDIT**

docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3.4'

services:

  config-service:
    image: im/config-service
    container_name: config-service
    environment:
     - SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE=native
    volumes:
     - ~/production-logs:/logs

  discovery-service:
    image: im/discovery-service
    container_name: discovery-service
    environment:
     - SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE=production
    volumes:
     - ~/production-logs:/logs

  gateway-service:
    image: im/gateway-service
    container_name: gateway-service
    ports:
     - "8080:8080"
    depends_on:
     - config-service
     - discovery-service
    environment:
     - SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE=production
    volumes:
     - ~/production-logs:/logs

  car-service_db:
    image: postgres:9.5
    container_name: car-service_db
    environment:
     - POSTGRES_DB=car
     - POSTGRES_USER=user
     - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=pass

  car-service:
    image: im/car-service
    container_name: car-service
    depends_on:
     - config-service
     - discovery-service
     - car-service_db
    environment:
     - SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE=production
     - CAR_SERVICE_DB_URL=jdbc:postgresql://car-service_db:5432/car
     - CAR_SERVICE_DB_USER=user
     - CAR_SERVICE_DB_PASSWORD=pass
    volumes:
     - ~/production-logs:/logs
```

Dockerfile of car-service

```
FROM openjdk:8-jdk-alpine
VOLUME /tmp
EXPOSE 9005
ARG JAR_FILE
ADD ${JAR_FILE} app.jar
ENV JAVA_OPTS="-agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,address=8001,server=y,suspend=n"
ENTRYPOINT ["sh", "-c", "java $JAVA_OPTS -Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom -jar /app.jar"]
```

Command used to start up

```
docker-compose up
```

Test machine: 
Ubuntu Server 16.04 LTS

Comment: Please provide us with code samples of what you tried until now. That way we can help you more effectively.

Comment: Can You narrow what kind of code sample would you like to see?

Comment: The commands you use to start all up. The docker-compose file. The Dockerfile definitions. That kind of stuff.  What type of computer you are using...

Comment: I edited my original question

Answer (score 1):

**RESOLVED**

The cause was logging aspect. I realized a lot of threads waiting on:

```
sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Unsafe.java:-2) native
    java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:175)
        java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.parkAndCheckInterrupt(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:836)
        java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.acquireQueued(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:870)
        java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.acquire(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:1199)
        java.util.concurrent.locks.ReentrantLock$NonfairSync.lock(ReentrantLock.java:209)
        java.util.concurrent.locks.ReentrantLock.lock(ReentrantLock.java:285)
        ch.qos.logback.core.OutputStreamAppender.writeBytes(OutputStreamAppender.java:197)
        ch.qos.logback.core.OutputStreamAppender.subAppend(OutputStreamAppender.java:231)
        ch.qos.logback.core.OutputStreamAppender.append(OutputStreamAppender.java:102)
        ch.qos.logback.core.UnsynchronizedAppenderBase.doAppend(UnsynchronizedAppenderBase.java:84)
        ch.qos.logback.core.spi.AppenderAttachableImpl.appendLoopOnAppenders(AppenderAttachableImpl.java:51)
        ch.qos.logback.classic.Logger.appendLoopOnAppenders(Logger.java:270)
        ch.qos.logback.classic.Logger.callAppenders(Logger.java:257)
        ch.qos.logback.classic.Logger.buildLoggingEventAndAppend(Logger.java:421)
        ch.qos.logback.classic.Logger.filterAndLog_2(Logger.java:414)
        ch.qos.logback.classic.Logger.debug(Logger.java:490)
```

Comment: And what did you do about it?